# Programmatically Determining when a Variable is a Set

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to determine whether a variable is a Set of not in NodeJS?

That is, this code

```
let thing1 = new Set([1,2,3])
let thing2 = [1,2,3]

console.log(typeof thing1)
console.log(typeof thing2)
```

reports that both variables contain an `object`

```
object
object
```

Is there a built-in way to determine if one variable contains a set or not?  If not, is there a common heuristic used to determine if a variable is a set or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried instanceof?

```
let thing1 = new Set([1,2,3])
let thing2 = [1,2,3]

console.log(thing1 instanceof Set)
console.log(thing2 instanceof Set)
```